# How to compare current and manual NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

there is a function where option NSDate is specified putting up manually.
How can I prevent execution of the function with the parameter of time, less than the current time?
I have tried this

```
if ([currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate: myTime] < 0)
```

but unfortunately sometimes it doesn't work 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to convert both the date to timeIntervals using `timeIntervalSince1970`

```
int interval1 = [date1 timeIntervalSince1970];
int interval2 = [date2 timeIntervalSince1970];

if(interval1 > interval2) //etc...
```

Comment: The types there should be `NSTimeInterval` (which is a `typedef`'d `double`), not `int`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to compare the current date with your custom date. More specifically, if the current date takes place **after** myTime, then the condition should be true.

```
if ([[NSDate date] compare: myTime] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"Current date is later than myTime");        
}
```

To the opposite, you would check the comparison against `NSOrderedAscending`.